# How can I find the longest names (by letters) in my data set?

Tags: r

I have a problem set that wants me to find out the "two longest names given to at least 1000 US babies" in the 'babynames' data set.

The code that I've tried in the past is this:

```
babynames %>%
  mutate(long.name = str_count(babynames$name,
                     "[:alpha:]")) %>%
  filter(n >= 1000) %>%
  arrange(-long.name) %>%
  head(2) %>%
  select(name, long.name)
```

But it gave me this:

```
name        long.name
  <chr>           <int>
1 Christopher        11
2 Christopher        11
```

By group_by name, I'm hoping to eliminate the issue above.
This is where I'm currently at:

```
babynames %>%
  filter(n >= 1000) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(long.name = str_count(babynames$name,
                                  "[:alpha:]")) %>%
  arrange(-long.name) %>%
  head(2)
```

I'm expecting to get something like:

```
name        long.name
  <chr>           <int>
1 Christopher        11
2 (some name)        10
```

But I get this:

```
Error: Column `long.name` must be length 1 (the group size), not 1924665
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `group_by` `name` and `sum` all the occurrence of each name, keep only those names which have occurred more than 1000 times, calculate the length using `nchar` and select top 2 values.

```
library(babynames)
library(dplyr)

babynames %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  filter(n > 1000) %>%
  mutate(name_length = nchar(name)) %>%
  #Can also do 
  #mutate(name_length = stringr::str_count(name, "[:alpha:]")) %>%
  top_n(2, name_length)

#  name              n name_length
#  <chr>         <int>       <int>
#1 Maryelizabeth  1969          13
#2 Michaelangelo  1236          13
```